# Python appending a list in a for loop with numpy array data

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, typeerror

I am writing a program that will append a list with a single element pulled from a 2 dimensional numpy array. So far, I have:

```
# For loop to get correlation data of selected (x,y) pixel for all bands
zdata = []
for n in d.bands:
    cor_xy = np.array(d.bands[n])
    zdata.append(cor_xy[y,x])
```

Every time I run my program, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/sdelgadi/scr/plot_pixel_data.py", line 36, in <module>
        cor_xy = np.array(d.bands[n])
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

My method works when I try it from the python interpreter without using a loop, i.e.

```
>>> zdata = []
>>> a = np.array(d.bands[0])     
>>> zdata.append(a[y,x])
>>> a = np.array(d.bands[1])
>>> zdata.append(a[y,x])
>>> print(zdata)
[0.59056658, 0.58640128]
```

What is different about creating a for loop and doing this manually, and how can I get my loop to stop causing errors?

Comment: What does `d.bands` look like?

Comment: You're treating `n` as if it's an index into `d.bands` when it's an element of `d.bands`.

Comment: @AnandSKumar 'd.bands' is a list of 50x50 2 dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're treating `n` as if it's an index into `d.bands` when it's an element of `d.bands`

```
zdata = []
for n in d.bands:
    cor_xy = np.array(n)
    zdata.append(cor_xy[y,x])
```

You say `a = np.array(d.bands[0])` works.  The first `n` should be exactly the same thing as `d.bands[0]`.  If so then `np.array(n)` is all you need.